# NSUrlREquest adding customised header

Tags: cocoa, url

How can I add HTTP header in the `NSUrlRequest`. 
I am using

```
[newRequest addValue:@"MY-APP" forHTTPHeaderField:@"NativeApp"];
[newRequest setValue:@"MY-APP" forHTTPHeaderField:@"NativeApp"];
```

I am able to see the previous predefined headers. But not able to add them. How can I add my own header?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer  was sending wrong request from the delegates. After adding we need to send the new NSURLRequest.

-(NSURLRequest *)webView:(WebView *)sender
                resource:(id)identifier
         willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
        redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
          fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource
{

}